# How to fix error:" Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk"

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms, apk, accelerometer, sensors

Hey when I run my code I get the error: Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk. I am building an App with Xamarin.forms and have Plugins( https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DeviceSensorsPlugin ) installed to read Sensor data.

```
03-26 06:21:42.956 D/OpenGLRenderer( 4376): HWUI GL Pipeline
03-26 06:21:43.475 D/Mono    ( 4376): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-26 06:21:43.475 D/Mono    ( 4376): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:43.475 D/Mono    ( 4376): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:43.476 D/Mono    ( 4376): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:43.847 D/Mono    ( 4376): Image addref System.Xml[0xca4a39a0] -> System.Xml.dll[0xca4aec00]: 2
03-26 06:21:43.851 D/Mono    ( 4376): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Xml' (System.Xml.dll)
03-26 06:21:43.852 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly System.Xml[0xca4a39a0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-26 06:21:43.854 D/Mono    ( 4376): AOT: image 'System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.ButtonDemos-sgjRMHCZclfsPhNQ__DHwQ==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
03-26 06:21:43.855 D/Mono    ( 4376): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.ButtonDemos-sgjRMHCZclfsPhNQ__DHwQ==/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
03-26 06:21:43.855 D/Mono    ( 4376): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Xml.dll.config'.
03-26 06:21:43.855 D/Mono    ( 4376): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config'.
03-26 06:21:43.855 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xeb5bc8c0] -> System.Xml[0xca4a39a0]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]
03-26 06:21:43.864 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0xca4a39a0] -> mscorlib[0xe2040e20]: 33
03-26 06:21:43.996 D/Mono    ( 4376): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-26 06:21:43.996 D/Mono    ( 4376): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
03-26 06:21:43.996 D/Mono    ( 4376): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
03-26 06:21:43.996 D/Mono    ( 4376): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
03-26 06:21:44.424 D/        ( 4376): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xca1dfa80, tid 4412
03-26 06:21:44.460 I/zygote  ( 4376): android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
03-26 06:21:44.460 I/OpenGLRenderer( 4376): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-26 06:21:44.460 D/OpenGLRenderer( 4376): Swap behavior 1
03-26 06:21:44.460 W/OpenGLRenderer( 4376): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-26 06:21:44.464 D/OpenGLRenderer( 4376): Swap behavior 0
03-26 06:21:44.697 D/EGL_emulation( 4376): eglCreateContext: 0xe3784120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
03-26 06:21:45.080 D/EGL_emulation( 4376): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3784120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3783330)
03-26 06:21:45.084 E/eglCodecCommon( 4376): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-26 06:21:45.084 E/eglCodecCommon( 4376): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-26 06:21:45.452 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref ButtonDemos.Android[0xeb5bb1e0] -> Xamarin.Essentials[0xeb5bc500]: 2
03-26 06:21:45.817 D/Mono    ( 4376): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-26 06:21:45.818 D/Mono    ( 4376): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:45.820 D/Mono    ( 4376): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:45.820 D/Mono    ( 4376): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
03-26 06:21:45.968 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0xeb5bba80] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xeb5bb9c0]: 4
03-26 06:21:46.189 W/zygote  ( 4376): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.ViewRenderer_2
03-26 06:21:46.335 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xeb5bc680] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xeb5bb9c0]: 5
03-26 06:21:46.335 D/Mono    ( 4376): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xeb5bb9c0] -> Java.Interop[0xeb5bc980]: 9
03-26 06:21:47.861 I/Choreographer( 4376): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-26 06:21:47.977 W/View    ( 4376): requestLayout() improperly called by md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ScrollViewContainer{a40ad95 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1584} during layout: running second layout pass
03-26 06:21:48.137 D/EGL_emulation( 4376): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3784120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3783330)
03-26 06:21:49.085 I/Choreographer( 4376): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-26 06:21:49.091 W/View    ( 4376): requestLayout() improperly called by md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.NavigationPageRenderer{28c7f97 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1731 #1} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
03-26 06:22:07.127 W/zygote  ( 4376): Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk
```